# How to boost a document score in Solr based on a Date field and DIstance field without specifying a distance range?

Tags: solr, geospatial

I am constructing a query that searches on the tile. I would like to boost the doc score based on the distance and a date field. Can this be achieved without restricting the distance and date field to a range?

What would the query be if the query field is title and sfield is latlon?

Answer (score 0):

boost to 'wildcarded' distance and date fields, i.e: [* TO *] ?